# Dependency Property Update Mechanism

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-properties

I have a custom control which is having a dependency property defined in it and my control implements INotifyPropertyChanged interface.

Dependency Property is Collection of Custom Objects.

Scenario 1

DP is of type List, whatever change I make in the list, nothing updated in MainUI, because I believe WPF does not understand adding and removing objects in list. it understands completely new references so to achieve this, whenever I want to update my list on control I use

MyProperty=new List();

In this approach, my DP callback fires everytime but eventArgs.NewValue always remains zero(it updated the list on UI correctly) but because I need to write some logic in property changed callback based on e.NewItems.Count, in this case that didn't work. Please tell me why e.NewItems does not work.

Scenario 2

DP is of type ObservableCollection, so as my collection property in view model against which I am binding my DP. in this case my property change callbacks does not fire at all, because I never use "new" keyword again after initialzing the property first time. UI updates but property change still not fires. So my logic in property change call back does not gets executed.

How should I make any of them or both of them working.

Comment: That's wrong. `INotifyPropertyChanged` is intended for regular (non-DependencyObject) POCO objects. You don't need to implement that in a custom control.

Comment: @HighCore Agreed with you, my bad. But removing that does not solve the actual problem. Please help me with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the ObservableCollection approach, and subscribe to it's `CollectionChanged` event.
That way you will get notified whenever the collection has been changed.

But the other approach should work as well. When you set the regular list to a new instance, the `PropertyChangedCallback` will be fired for the dependency property, and by examining the `DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs` object you can get the new value.

XAML:

```
<StackPanel>
    <Button Content="Add to observablecollection" Click="click1" />
    <Button Content="Set list to new instance" Click="click2" />
</StackPanel>
```

Code-behind:

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    public ObservableCollection<string> Strings { get; set; }

    public List<string> StringsList
    {
        get { return (List<string>)GetValue(StringsListProperty); }
        set { SetValue(StringsListProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty StringsListProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("StringsList", typeof(List<string>), typeof(Window), new PropertyMetadata(null, StringsListPropertyChanged));

    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Strings = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        Strings.CollectionChanged += strings_CollectionChanged;

        StringsList = new List<string> { "Test1", "Test2", "Test3", "Test4" };
    }

    void strings_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Fires everytime the observablecollection has an item added/removed etc.
        MessageBox.Show(string.Format("ObservableCollection has changed! Count is now {0}", this.Strings.Count.ToString()));

        if (this.Strings.Count == 10)
            Console.WriteLine("Collection contains 10 strings!!");
    }

    private static void StringsListPropertyChanged(DependencyObject e, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        var newCount = ((List<string>)args.NewValue).Count.ToString();
        MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Dependency property has changed! Count is now {0}", newCount));
    }

    private void click1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Strings.Add("Test1");
    }

    private void click2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.StringsList = new List<string> { "Newitem1", "Newitem2" };
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the thing is In case I go for ObservableCollection way and subscribe to CollectionChanged event, it will not only execute every time the collection is changed but for each single item in the collection. If my collection has 100 records this event will execute 100 times, so this event will not be a good place to run any  logic in it as I don't want to execute that logic multiple times. And for other approach in property changed it gives null for eventargs.new items.

Comment: No, the CollectionChanged event will be raised once every time you add or remove an item. If you have 100 items in the collection, and add one more, it will not be raised 101 times just 1. And if the NewValue property on the DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs is null for you, you are doing something wrong. Have you tried the code i've written?

Answer (score 0):

ObservableCollection inherits from both INotifyPropertyChanged and INotifyCollectionChanged.  I think if you want to know when the collection changed you should use this interface:

[INotifyCollectionChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Collections.Specialized.INotifyCollectionChanged.aspx)